# Django not serializing the natural key values

Tags: python, django

I have a django model where i use natural keys:

```
class AcademicProgramsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, acad_program_id, program_title, required_credits):
    return self.get(acad_program_id = acad_program_id, program_title = program_title, required_credits = required_credits)

class AcademicPrograms(models.Model):

    objects = AcademicProgramsManager()
    acad_program_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    acad_program_category = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramCategories)
    acad_program_type = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramTypes)
    acad_program_code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    program_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    required_credits = models.IntegerField()
    min_gpa = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class StudentAcademicPrograms(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    academic_program = models.ForeignKey(AcademicPrograms)
    credits_completed = models.IntegerField()
    academic_program_gpa = models.FloatField()
    primary_program = models.BooleanField()
```

But my serializer still does not output the elements of the foreign key

```
[
{
  "pk": 1, 
  "model": "studentapp.studentacademicprograms", 
  "fields": {
    "academic_program": 124, 
    "credits_completed": 32, 
    "primary_program": true, 
    "student": 1206, 
    "academic_program_gpa": 3.7
  }
},
{
  "pk": 2, 
  "model": "studentapp.studentacademicprograms", 
  "fields": {
    "academic_program": 123, 
    "credits_completed": 32, 
    "primary_program": false, 
    "student": 1206, 
    "academic_program_gpa": 3.4
  }
}
]
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `def natural_key(self)` method to your `AcademicPrograms` model. You must also pass `use_natural_foreign_keys=True` or `use_natural_primary_keys=True` when serializing. See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys) for an example.